# Using directory to store information and keep this information in a App Update

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store

I have an app that stores images from the user in the app/documents folder, I'm doing the following code determine the path to save it:

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docs = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *imageFilename = [[[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:self.nextID] stringValue] stringByAppendingFormat:@".jpg"];
    NSString *dirPath = [docs stringByAppendingFormat:@"/Photos/"];
    imagePath = [dirPath stringByAppendingString:imageFilename];
```

it gives me a path similar to (in simulator):
    /var/mobile/Applications/C9C43CFD-6A5F-40CF-8BAE-20496B5A544A/Documents/Photos/1.jpg

I save this path to show this image when I need.

My problem is, when I sent an update in the app store, after update the app it cant show the images anymore.
My understand is the Documents folder cant change when update the app in AppStore.

My probably reason for that it the name between Applications folder and Documentar has changed, is it true when update a app version from AppStore?

Does anyone has any idea? is there any way to test this app update local?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the relative path after the `Documents` directory, not the absolute path. The app's directory can change during an update but the structure inside the app's sandbox won't change.

Also, there is a slightly better way to build your path:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docs = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imageFilename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg", self.nextID];
NSString *dirPath = [docs stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Photos"];
imagePath = [dirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageFilename];
```

Answer (score 0):

When the app is updated from the App Store, the contents of the Documents directory are unchanged. The app bundle and all its contents are replaced with the new version, but the Documents folder is a safe place to store content between app versions.